# How to Limit Records of IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using IEnumerable for a dynamic list. I am trying to limit the number of records to displays like at max 5 records. Any ideas on how to?

Comment: .Take() and .Skip() is your friend :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Please upload your code so that we can help you.

Comment: ProductsList = _unitofWork.Products.GetAll(includeProperties: "Category,ProductType,ProductSize")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As comment said, **.Take()** is a good choice for your requirment.

I created an example based on `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` with `.Take()`, you can refer it:

```
int recordCount = 5;
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> data= _context.TableName.OrderBy(x => x.ID)
                                  .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.ID.ToString() })
                                  .Take(recordCount).ToList();
```

After debugging, data will present **the first five pieces of data** sorted by ID in the form of `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

---

### Update

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var allData = _context.TableC.OrderBy(x => x.ID).ToList();

            int recordCount = 5;
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> data = _context.TableC.OrderBy(x => x.ID).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.ID.ToString() }).Take(recordCount).ToList();

            ViewBag.DropDownData2 = data;
            return View(allData);
        }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication_core_mvc.Models.TableC>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<h3>All data:</h3>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Stauts</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.ID</td>
            <td>@item.Name</td>
            <th>@item.Status</th>
        </tr>
    }
</table>


<h3>DropDownList1:</h3>
@Html.DropDownList("TableC",
                      Model.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.ID.ToString() }).Take(5).ToList(),
                    "Select Data",
                    new { @class = "form-control" })

<h3>DropDownList2:</h3>
@Html.DropDownList("TableC",
                     (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DropDownData2,
                    "Select Data",
                    new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Here is the new result:

[image]

Comment: ProductsList = _unitofWork.Products.GetAll(includeProperties: "Category,ProductType,ProductSize").Take(count).ToList() // Will this do the trick ??

Comment: @AliZubair, Since you didn't provide detailed code, we don't know what the `GetAll ` method returns? I suggest you to debug the code test directly, if there is no exception, it means feasible.

Comment: GetAll method returns all the records stored in database. ProductList is an IEnumerable<SelectListItem> to display all the records which I originally used it for displaying DropDown List but it also works in displaying all records in a View by using @foreach method in View. IncludeProperties add other model data inside this model. So the only thing left is to limit the number of records it would pick and display in View.

Comment: @AliZubair, Do you mean that there are two places for your view to use the data returned by GetAll ? One needs to display all, the other is that dropdownlist only needs a part of it, right? If so , you can use  `.Take()`  for the Model when binding dropdownlist data source, or you can use `ViewBag` to transfer dropdownlist data source.

Comment: Yes Exactly!! Thanks!!